# Matlab vs. Pandas concatenate Matrices

Tags: pandas, matlab

a pandas array shall be stacked ontop/below a given pandas dataframe. I'm using this code but the result is really surprising!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pprint

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['lib', 'qty1', 'qty2'])
for i in range(3):
    df.loc[i] = [np.random.randint(-10,10) for n in range(3)]

df2 = df.iloc[0]

pp.pprint(df)
pp.pprint(df2)

print("\nLast row")
df=pd.concat([df,df2],axis=0)
pp.pprint(df)

print("\nFirst row")
df=pd.concat([df2,df],axis=0)
pp.pprint(df)
```

This is so simple, how can I make the concat work like in Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `df2 = df.iloc[0]`, you create a `Series` object as you'll see if you do `print(type(df2))`. In order to get `pd.concat` to work in the way you want, you need to concatenate `DataFrame` objects only. One way to get the slice of the frame as you intend is to do:

```
df2 = df.iloc[0:1,:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the comprehensive solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pprint

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['lib', 'qty1', 'qty2'])
for i in range(3):
    df.loc[i] = [np.random.randint(-10,10) for n in range(3)]

df2 = df.iloc[0:1,:]

print("The two are:")
pp.pprint(df)
pp.pprint(df2)

print("\n...insert as last:")
df_erg1=pd.concat([df,df2])
pp.pprint(df_erg1)

print("\n...insert as first:")
df_erg2=pd.concat([df2,df])
pp.pprint(df_erg2)
```